# WinRT - Create a custom ListView control with specific ItemContainerStyle

Tags: c#, listview, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have created a *WinRT* class libary for *Windows Phone 8.1* with different reusable UI controls. Now, I want to create a custom `ListView` control with a default  `ItemContainerStyle`. In this way, I do not need to set the ItemContainerStyle in all different projects.

So, I've created two files:

- a `CustomListView` class which inherits from `ListView`
- a `CustomListView.xaml` resource dictionary with a `CustomListViewItemStyle` style, target type `ListViewItem`. this file will be merged into the `Themes/generic.xaml` resource dictionary.

Within the contstructor of CustomListView I set the ItemContainerStyle:

```
ItemContainerStyle = Resources["CustomListViewItemStyle"] as Style;
```

This does not work, I get the following error: *WinRT-Information: Cannot find a resource with the given key.*

Also the move of the style from my custom resource dictionary to `generic.xaml` doesn't help.

What am I doing wrong?

### EDIT

My Themes/Generic.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:XYZ.Apps.UI">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/TabPanel/TabPanel.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/CustomListView/CustomListView.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Hmm normally the way to reach them is this: Application.Current.Resources[""]

Comment: The application class is not available in a class library.

Comment: Yeah true, so actually not sure how to pull this off

Comment: try using Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Current.Resources["CustomListViewItemStyle"] as Style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand what you want. As a follow-on example, I would love it if the controls team would default the HorizontalContentAlignment to Stretch instead of Left as it is now. Creating a CustomListView could do this.

First, let's address your current approach. In short, perfect. But there's probably something you do not understand about templated controls, and that is that the style in generic.xaml is automatically applied and you do not need to setup the style in code-behind if you do it in the style.

Hopefully you have something like this:

```
<Style Target='ListView'>
    <Setter Property='ItemContainerStyle'>
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style Target='ListViewItem'>
                <Setter Property='HorizontalContentAlignment' Value='Stretch' />
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Of course, that is just quick typing and not exact syntax, but hopefully you can make sense of it. The code above would be placed in themes/generic.xaml and the platform would apply this before it applied anything in the scope of app, page, or control (in that order).

Remember

1. Only have a single Target=ListView style
2. Don't include x:Key in this case

This works. I can verify this because I do it.

Now, to your question. Why is yours not working? My thought as to why yours is not working is because it is not properly being merged into generic.xaml. As a quick test, take your style and just manually copy it into generic.xaml. See if that works. If it is does then your merge syntax is the problem.

Without more information, this is the best debugging I can do about your problem. It's worth telling you that this works. That's the hope you need to continue, I imagine. Your problem might be in some subtle syntax error or the merge, I can't be sure. But you'll get it.

Best of luck.

Comment: If I use this style with target type ListView, will this be applied to all ListViews within my class libary or to all ListViews within the consuming projects (projects which reference my class libary)?

Comment: You were right - it was a problem with the merging of the different resource dictionaries into generic.xaml, and the build type of generic.xaml was 'Content' instead of 'Page'. What is the right way of merging multiple resource dictionaries into one single generic.xaml? I'd like to have single files because they are better to maintain. EDIT: I added my current generic.xaml into my question.

Answer (score -1):

It is not finding the app wide resource. Try this

```
App.Current.Resources["CustomListViewItemStyle"] as Style
```

Comment: The app class is not available within a class library.